# Use Excel sheet to create dictionary in order to replace values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file with product names. First row is the category (A1: Water, A2: Sparkling, A3:Still, B1: Soft Drinks, B2: Coca Cola, B3: Orange Juice, B4:Lemonade etc.), each cell below is a different product. I want to keep this list in a viewable format (not comma separated etc.) as this is very easy for anybody to update the product names (I have a second person running the script without understanding the script)

[image: A1: Water, A2: Sparkling, A3:Still, B1: Soft Drinks, B2: Coca Cola, B3: Orange Juice, B4:Lemonade etc.]

If it helps I can also have the excel file in a CSV format and I can also move the categories from the top row to the first column

[image: Alternative format of Excel file]

I would like to replace the cells of a dataframe (df) with the product categories. For example, Coca Cola would become Soft Drinks. If the product is not in the excel it would not be replaced (ex. Cookie).

```
print(df)

       Product  Quantity
0      Coca Cola  1234
1      Cookie     4
2      Still      333
3      Chips      88
```

Expected Outcome:

```
print (df1)

       Product      Quantity
0      Soft Drinks   1234
1      Cookie        4
2      Water         333
3      Snacks        88
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) or [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for helper `Series` and then use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
s = df1.melt().dropna().set_index('value')['variable']
```

Alternative:

```
s = df1.stack().reset_index(name='v').set_index('v')['level_1']
```

---

```
df['Product'] = df['Product'].replace(s)
#if performance is important
#df['Product'] = df['Product'].map(s).fillna(df['Product'])
print (df)
       Product  Quantity
0  Soft Drinks      1234
1       Cookie         4
2        Water       333
3       Snacks        88
```